# Powershell Get number from string

Tags: powershell, replace

Hi all I am trying to get the number from a users id using powershell

The format we use is the first letter of the first name, first four letters of the last name and studentid so a student with the name John Smith with Id# 123456 would be jsmit123456
the problem I get if the user has less than 4 letters in their name.
so using substring would give and error for those id's

I tried select-string, -match, trim, trimstart, trimend

here is my code so far

```
$name = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=edu" 
-Filter {Created -ge $checktime}     
|Select-Object SAMAccountName

foreach($object in $name){
$object
$studentid = $object.SAMAccountName.Substring(5,6)
$studentid
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Id does not exist as another attribute in your Directory (uid). It's not so clean with a tool like a dirctory to store two datas in te same attribte.

Comment: You work in the defense industry don't you?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is simple to do with a regex:

```
 ('jsmit123456') -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'

 123456
```

\D+ = all the non-digits, \d+ = all the digits that follow.

```
 $studentid = $object.SAMAccountName -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
```

Comment: just for fun: `-join ( "jsmit123456" )[-6..-1]` (if ID is always six digit )

Comment: In this case `-replace '\D+'` should suffice.

Comment: Only @Joey answer worked for me. The @mjolinor answer returned `5}`

Comment: @KolobCanyon: That's because in your case the digits are *before* the non-digits.

Comment: How do you stop at the first occurrence in the string? Let's say i got `jsmit123456lololol123lol22`, how do i extract only `123456`?

Comment: SED style used.

Comment: SED style used.

Answer (score 37):

For readability reasons (which I sometimes find difficult with regexp) I would prefer this solution:

```
'john123456smith' -replace "[^0-9]" , ''

123456
```

Replace everything which is not a number, [^0-9], with nothing, ''. This does not involve the $1 syntax (the string matched by the regex)

Answer (score 6):

Slightly different than OP's question, but I landed here seeking my answer, so...

If there is a "second" set of digits in the string, none of these work correctly to extract the FIRST number in the string.

For instance, using the other answers on the string "asld_1234_asdf3" produces things like "12343" (extra "3" appended to the number).

My real use case has a delimiter - the "_" - as in the example:

```
    $str = "asld_1234_asdf3";
    $str -replace '.*_([0-9]*)_.*','$1'
    # produces: 1234
```

If delimiters aren't in play, you need this one (which also works for the case above WITH delimiters, incidentally):

```
    $str = "asldX1234Yasdf3";
    $str -replace '\D+([0-9]*).*','$1' 
    # produces: 1234
```

Both of the above produce "1234" as required for my case.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a regex which is some more generic. 
For example, to cover non-digit characters before AND after the value. Ex: ??XXXX12345YYYY**

You should use:

```
('??XXXX12345YYYY**') -replace '\D+(\d+)\D+','$1'

$studentid = $object.SAMAccountName -replace '\D+(\d+)\D+','$1'
```

12345

Answer (score 1):

```
Function ExtractNumbers ([string]$InStr){
   $Out = $InStr -replace("[^\d]")
   try{return [int]$Out}
       catch{}
   try{return [uint64]$Out}
       catch{return 0}}
```

Using:

```
$a = "a18афпа4sgsafd4r6!74y40:7-375+0(95)"
```

ExtractNumbers `$a`

```
(ExtractNumbers $a).gettype()
```