# Remove non-numeral characters from column of csv when importing into PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, csv

I am very new to coding. I am trying to filter a few thousand lines of csv test data using PowerShell.

I have a testing procedure which is completed on a large number of units. I need extract the data for a subset of these units.

When the test data is created, the unit number is entered manually. It is very common to have any number of other characters added to the 4 digit unit number at this time. For example, unit 1234 could appear as A1234, abc 1234, A1234Z, and so forth.

I would like to remove any non-number characters which appear in that column of my csv so I can extract the appropriate data.

I have written some code which extracts the data for unit numbers which match the list entries. I know that regex can be used to remove the letters ([like in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697408/powershell-get-number-from-string)), but I am not quite sure how to incorporate it into my code.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code so far

```
$UnitNumbers = "1234", "5678"
Import-Csv 'test.csv' |
Where { $_.UNIT_VC -in $UnitNumbers} |  
Export-Csv 'test1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the intent is to only export those rows whose `UNIT_VC` column contains one of the specified numbers, and to set those columns to just the number found:

```
Import-Csv 'test.csv' |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.UNIT_VC -match '1234|5678') {
      $_.UNIT_VC = $Matches[0]
      $_ # Output the modified object.
    }
  } | Export-Csv 'test1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```